# CMake - New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am using CMake version 3.19 and Boost version 1.75 in Windows Server 2008.
I also added environment variable "BOOST_ROOT" as shown below : [image: Environment Variable Boost Root]

However, I got the warning below while using CMake:

```
CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1204 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1326 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1935 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  dep/boost/CMakeLists.txt:47 (find_package)
```

Is there anyway to deal with the warning above? Thank you in advance

Comment: I'd prefer the config version of `find_package` to find boost. If you properly installed boost (i.e. you ran `b2.exe ... --prefix=C:/local/boost_1_75_0 ... install` or used an installer that installs the same files) there should be a directory `C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib/cmake` containing configuration scripts for the boost components you installed. These can be used by the config version of `find_package`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These warnings simply mean that your CMake version is older than your Boost version.
The CMake devs can update their dependency lists only after a new Boost release, so you need to update to a CMake version that was released after boost 1.75.

Look at the Boost version history: https://www.boost.org/users/history/ 
Boost 1.75 was released at 12/11/20.

Now look at the CMake version history: https://cmake.org/files/v3.19/ 
CMake 3.19.2 was the first version after that.

You should propably just go with the latest CMake release, 3.19.5.

Comment: Thank you! The latest version of CLion (2021.1.2) ships with cmake 3.19.2, which is not the latest cmake version and is thusly not compatible with the latest Boost lib version (1.76.0). I installed Boost 1.73.0 and now it works!